# Trying to fetch a member based on their nickname/displayname. Discord.js BOT

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Hi am i trying to take a user specified nickname for a member and fetch that members and get additional information about that user. Right now i have confirmed the ARGS[0] sent by the user is correct but i am getting a NULL response to the matched user. Not sure what i am missing. Thanks

This is my current code. Just trying to get the match working right now. I also need to consider if the person doesnt have a nickname to check the username. Or think would displayname property be better. Thanks

```
if(command === "memberinfo") {
    let sentNickname = args[0];
    message.channel.send(`Sent Nickname: ${sentNickname}`);
    const discordserver = client.guilds.get(DragonTS); // Define server to get information from


    discordserver.fetchMembers() // Fetch guild members
        .then()  //.then(console.log)
        .catch(console.error);
}       
    let matchedMember = discordserver.members.find(m => m.nickname === sentNickname);
    message.channel.send(`Matched Member ${matchedMember}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some parts of your code aren't executed. You need to put all your code into the `.then()`:

```js
if(command === "memberinfo") {
    let sentNickname = args[0];
    message.channel.send(`Sent Nickname: ${sentNickname}`);
    const discordserver = client.guilds.get(DragonTS); // Define server to get information from


    discordserver.fetchMembers() // Fetch guild members
        .then((serverWithFetchedMembers) => {
            let matchedMember = serverWithFetchedMembers.members.find(m => m.nickname === sentNickname);
            message.channel.send(`Matched Member ${matchedMember}`);
        })  //.then(console.log)
        .catch(console.error);

}
```

It will wait for the `fetchMembers()` function and execute your code after it!

Comment: I changed the code as you suggested but i am still getting a NULL return