# Discord JS - Reverse lookup to obtain userID from their display name

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

We're currently building a bot that will review specific messages and perform follow-up administrative actions on it. One of the actions will read a message and extract a named user (string - not link), search for it and return the ID of the user - which is then used elsewhere.

```js
if (message.channel.id === register) {
       // The post is in the register channel
       if (message.content.includes('doing business with you')) {
           //it's a successful claim
           Rclaimedby = message.content.match(/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/)[1];
           const Ruser = client.users.cache.find(user => user.username == Rclaimedby).id;
```

The text snippet will just have the individuals name as a string, which the regex will extract. If the individual doesn't have a nickname set, it'll work and the rest of the code works. However, as soon as that name isn't their "normal" name, it doesn't work and crashes with a TypeError.

I need to be able to use that stripped name and find the ID regardless of whether they have a nickname or not, but I've been searching for days (and a LOT of trial and error) and can't find a way around it.

To help, the message content would say something like:

> (...) doing business with you **normalname** (...) or
> (...) doing business with you **randomnickname** (...)

Help?

Comment: By username, do you mean the current display name (that can be changed for every server)?

Comment: Hey, yes indeed.  So in the example at the end, if I've been on the server and not set myself a nickname, I'll show as **normalusername** (no discriminator).  If I've set the nickname, I'll show as **randomnickname**.

I'm aware that the nickname is recorded at guild level, rather than user, but I cannot seem to find any way of searching backwards to get the ID of the individual.  The problem is, I can't control what the other bot spits out, and it spits the display name as text, so we're basically trying reverse lookups.

**EDIT: I should note that this will be a ONE SERVER bot**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you mentioned in your comment, the key difference between extracting a user's ID from their [`displayName`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=displayName) would mean you would have to get the [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) object first (it's server-specific) and then get the [`user`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=user) property from that.

All in all, it just requires a little bit of re-maneuvering around the variables in order to get what you want since the [`displayName`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=displayName) property is specific to each server.

---

### Process:

1. Get the server ID
2. From the server ID, get the server
3. Get the [`members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=members) property from the server
4. Find the member by matching it with the given **randomnickname**, which I've set as `displayNickname` in this case.
5. Get the [`user`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=user) property from the [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) object and grab the ID from there.

---

### Code:

This is merely something you can work off of.

```js
if (command === "memberinfo") {
    let serverID = "800743801526157383"; //server id; manually input your own
    let displayNickname = args[0];
    message.channel.send(`Sent Nickname: ${displayNickname}`);
    let serverMembers = client.guilds.cache.get(serverID).members //defines server and returns members
    let matchedMember = serverMembers.cache.find(m => m.displayName === displayNickname);
    message.channel.send(`Matched Member ${matchedMember.user.username}.`)
    console.log(`The user's ID: ${matchedMember.user.id}`);
}
```

---

### Resources:

- [SO Question - Fetching user from displayName](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59428709/15073477)
- [Discord.js Documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome)

Comment: Thank you! I've tried this out and, in the main, it seems to be working and it's allowing us to move on to the next step.  One thing I've noticed though, is it doesn't seem to handle/match certain names and will return as undefined, or, if I use the code as `let matchedMember = serverMembers.cache.find(m => m.displayName === displayNickname).id;` (the change being to add the .id for the returned value) - it will fall over because it can't find the id of 'undefined'.  As an example, we have a user with a nick like **randomnickname:tm:**. Returning a string, works fine, trying to compare doesnt.

Comment: As an additional note on this, a number of our users (as with most discord servers) have custom fonts and names - so it seems to either return as undefined, or die if we try to pull the id.  We've been testing and another user with "ʕʘ‿ʘʔ" in their name killed it. Returning the name shows it fine, but it never seems to recognise the match.

Comment: For the first comment, that's because you're trying to retrieve the `id` of a `GuildMember` (which is definitely possible but not what you want), you need to first access the `user` property. So you need to use `let matchedMember = serverMembers.cache.find(m => m.displayName === displayNickname).user.id;`

Comment: Also I tested out `ʕʘ‿ʘʔ` by setting it to my nickname and it worked. Maybe it's something else in your code? It could may as well have been the thing I mentioned above.

Comment: For those with a "normal" name - that seemed to work, however, acknowledge that it's not the best way to handle it.  What's confusing at this stage, is that for those with "abnormal" names (i.e. the random characters noted above) are all returning as `undefined` even if there's no `.id` or `.user.id`.  It's like it's not matching the names. I am fairly new to Discord, so apologies, but this one has me scratching my head!

Comment: I'm not exactly certain what may be happening on your end, but I've tested it (the code I've displayed above) and it works even with a nickname like `ʕʘ‿ʘʔ`

Comment: Interestingly, I've tried this on `NormalNickname` and `AbnormalNickname ʕʘ‿ʘʔ` and it works fine and the code runs through, returning the ID that I need.  However, there's another user `kywah ʕʘ‿ʘʔ` that it immediately stops with `TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined` pointing towards the `.user.id`.  I can see the user is there, I've copied the exact name to use in the test posts, I've console.log'd the post-regex response (which goes into the `Rclaimedby` variable) and it's there... it just dies at the attempt to grab the ID.

Comment: Maybe split it into different chunks like I've done through the messages? And then `console.log()` the various variables from there.

Comment: That's what I've been trying. So, the setting of Rclaimed by has not changed, and when console.log'ing it, it returns `Rclaimedby set to: "kywah ʕʘ‿ʘʔ"` - with the captured text only in " so I could check for leading/trailing whitespace. `let serverMembers = client.guilds.cache.get(serverID).members;` and then `let Ruser = serverMembers.cache.find(m => m.displayName === Rclaimedby);` follows and a console.log returns `Ruser set to: undefined`. So, it looks like it's not finding the person, but I'm staring at them and have copy-pasted names etc. into the messages (and even compared).

Comment: Does the person share a server with the bot? Just checking for the basic foundations, etc.

Comment: Yes, the member is on both the LIVE server and TEST server with myself and the bot. The LIVE server is owned by another member; the TEST server is owned by myself. Both myself and that particular member are admins on both servers.

Comment: Well, there's nothing unique about the username `kywah ʕʘ‿ʘʔ` since I tested it on myself and it works just fine. There may be some other property interfering with the search.

Comment: Thanks @PerplexingParadox.  Technically, the question I originally asked has been answered by your suggestion, so it's only fair to mark it as so.  I'll continue investigating this other issue with the names - and test with a lot more names - so see if I can get it sorted.  Thanks for your time; patience and attention on this.

Comment: I hope you will find the solution sometime soon!